# JavaScript: How to prevent loadscrollPagination function to be loaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project using the jquery-scroll-pagination plugin to dynamic load additional content when scrolling: https://github.com/andferminiano/jquery-scroll-pagination

The idea is to facilitate the user with different views. This is currently being done by using the jquery load event in a way that when an user clicks a button the content will be loaded.

The problem I'm facing is that the "scrollPagination" functions remains in memory and being active on #content. If an user clicks away the view and switches back, the scrollPagination for #content is loaded a second time. All calls are executed twice then.

Is there a way to prevent the scrollPagination function being active multiple times?

```
    function loadscrollPagination() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#content').scrollPagination({
                nop: 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
                offset: 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
                error: 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                delay: 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                scroll: true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls.
            });
        }, 100);
    }

    $("div.detail").click(function() {
        $('section').load('detailed-view.php', function() {
            loadscrollPagination();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `jQuery.one()` will do the trick:

```
#('section').one('load', 'detailed-view.php', function() {...})
```

See here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/one/